# Is there any way to use spring data r2dbc and spring data jpa together?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a webflux application that I use JPA repository and hibernate in it, But I need reactive transaction management too , for this I need to add spring data r2dbc to application.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use (Spring Data) JPA and (Spring Data) R2DBC in one application, but they don't really interoperate, so you can't have a repository or template that uses JPA and R2DBC.

Comment: what about a service with a @Transactional method that runs a JPA query and a R2DBC query in the same transaction?